# Compare two string elements in R

Tags: r, statistics

I want to compare two string elements in R. The `str()` function of the two elemets gives me:

```
> (str(announcmentDate))
 chr "24.08.2009"
NULL
> (str(totalReturnsOfCompanyData$Date))
 chr [1:3036] "01.01.2002" "02.01.2002" "03.01.2002" "04.01.2002" ...
NULL
>
```

I tried:

```
> for (i in totalReturnsOfCompanyData$Date) {
+   if (totalReturnsOfCompanyData$Date[i]==announcmentDate[1]) {
+       
+       print("YUPIDUUUUUUUUUS")        
+   }
+ }
Error in if (totalReturnsOfCompanyData$Date[i] == announcmentDate[1]) { : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

Why am I getting this error? Is there an `equal` function(like in java) in R to show that the strings are equal?

I appreciate your answer!

**UPDATE**

I am using a for loop because I need the index later to extract a subsample from the data.

When I try:

```
> for (i in totalReturnsOfCompanyData$Date) {
+   if (na.omit(totalReturnsOfCompanyData$Date[i])==announcmentDate[1]) {
+       
+   #   eventWindow120Before <-
+   #   eventWindow120After  <-
+       print("YUPIDUUUUUUUUUS")        
+   }
+ }
Error in if (na.omit(totalReturnsOfCompanyData$Date[i]) == announcmentDate[1]) { : 
  argument is of length zero
```

Why do I get this error?

Comment: what output are you getting if you enter (str(announcmentDate[1]))

Comment: @user3116916 I am getting `> (str(announcmentDate[1]))
 chr "24.08.2009"
NULL`

Comment: and (str(totalReturnsOfCompanyData$Date[1]))

Comment: @user3116916 I am getting `> (str(totalReturnsOfCompanyData$Date[1]))
 chr "01.01.2002"
NULL`

Comment: thx, you could try na.fail {stats} ->na.omit(object, ...)

Comment: Looks like the values of `i` in your loop are not indices but the actual elements of `totalRe..`. Try `seq_along(totalRe..)` instead.

Comment: You get the `argument of length zero` error because you remove the NA inside the `if` statement, leading to an empty content. You need to remove the NA's form the source data before entering the loop. However, there is no need for the loop in the first place, see my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you have some NA's in your totalReturns data frame. You can more easily do this with the following code:

```
announcmentDate =  c("24.08.2009")
totalReturnsOfCompanyData_Date = strsplit("01.01.2002 02.01.2002 03.01.2002 04.01.2002 24.08.2009 NA"," ")[[1]]
```

4 ways to get the intersect of the two:

```
subset(totalReturnsOfCompanyData_Date, totalReturnsOfCompanyData_Date == announcmentDate)
totalReturnsOfCompanyData_Date[totalReturnsOfCompanyData_Date == announcmentDate]
totalReturnsOfCompanyData_Date[which(totalReturnsOfCompanyData_Date %in% announcmentDate)]
intersect(totalReturnsOfCompanyData_Date, announcmentDate)
```

Or print something if your date is present (na.rm=TRUE will ignore NAs)

```
if(any(totalReturnsOfCompanyData_Date == announcmentDate, na.rm=TRUE))
{ print("Has it")  }
```

If you need the actual indices:

```
which(totalReturnsOfCompanyData_Date %in% announcmentDate)
```

There is rarely a need to do any looping in R, you can get the indices with the which statement above. I noticed you are also using event Windows. If they are rolling you might want to check out rollapply which I believe is in the MASS package to further get rid of any loops.

Answer (score 1):

What is going wrong probably is that there are NULL values in your `totalReturnsOfCompanyData$date` vector, which do not work with the `if` statement. You can simply remove the `NULL`'s using `na.omit`.

In addition, there is no need for the `for` loop, you can use vectorisation:

```
s = "24.08.2009"
l = c("01.01.2002", "02.01.2002", "03.01.2002", "24.08.2009", NA)
s == l
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  NA
which(s == l)
[1] 4
```

Note that this solution works without the `na.omit` because `NA` is interpreted as `FALSE`.

Comment: Thx for your answer! However now I am getting a different error! Please see my update.

Comment: If you use my vectorized approach the error you have will disappear.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are on the right way!
BUT: The contitionals evaluation of you if construct if `(totalReturnsOfCompanyData$Date[i]==announcmentDate[1])` must result a NA. - And since the conditional needs a 1 or 0 (true or false) you are getting the error. 
[na.omit()](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/stats/html/na.fail.html) should help you with this behaviour!

> Handle Missing Values in Objects:"These generic functions are useful for dealing with NAs in e.g., data frames. na.fail returns the object if it does not contain any missing values, and signals an error otherwise. na.omit returns the object with incomplete cases removed. na.pass returns the object unchanged."(1) http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/stats/html/na.fail.html

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! I tried it, however I am getting another error. Please see my update!

Comment: Try to let the na.omit() function to the announcmentDate & the totalReturnsOfCompanyData before entering your for-loop!

Answer (score 0):

First, the For loop is not the best approach in R. You should probably use vectorization.

If you want to use For loops for whatever reason, the For loop is looping over the date objects not the numbers. Inside your loop the variable i is the element of the loop rather than the index you think it is. Thus, I believe you should be typing

```
if (i==announcmentDate[1]) {
```

rather than

```
if (totalReturnsOfCompanyData$Date[i]==announcmentDate[1]) {
```

Comment: This makes no sense, the comparison should be between both dates, not between the date and an index.

Comment: Yes, but the user is looping over the objects in Date, so i is the date itself. Try it.

for (i in Date) {

+ print(i)

+ }